# How do I display results for one Id on a partial View MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to display reservations for the current logged in restaurant but I am getting the following error.

*The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RestaurantApplication.Models.Restaurant]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[RestaurantApplication.Models.RestaurantReservationEvent]'.*

Here is my controller

```
public ActionResult RestaurantReservationsPartialView()
    {
string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        var restaurantID = (from r in db.Restaurants
                            where r.OwnerId == currentUserId
                            select r).ToList();

        ViewBag.RestaurantId = restaurantID;

return PartialView("_RestaurantReservations", restaurantID);
```

And this is the view Calling the PartialView

```
<div style="padding-top: 50px;">
@Html.Action("RestaurantReservationsPartialView")
</div>
```

Here is the Partial view which I want to display the list of reservations for the current logged in restaurant.

```
@if (ViewBag.numReservations > 0 && ViewBag.ReservationStatus == "Pending")
{
<center><p id="pendingReservations">Here are your pending reservations</p>
</center>
<div class="row">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <center><h1 class="panel-title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookersName)</h1></center>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h3 style="font-size: 16px">Booking Description: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookingDesc) <br />
                Number of people: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookingNumberOfPeople)</h3>
                <h3 style="font-size: 15px">
                    <h>Booking Date: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookingDate) at</h>
                    <h>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookingStartTime)</h>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <center>@Html.ActionLink("Accept", "AcceptReservation", new { id = item.RestaurantReservationEventID }, new { @class = "btn btn-success btn-xs" }) @Html.ActionLink("Decline", "DeclineReservation", new { id = item.RestaurantReservationEventID }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs" })</center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

}

Comment: you need to pass a collection of `RestaurantReservationEvent` to the partial view. Also that is not a partial view call. It is executing an action method

Comment: Thanks @Shyju but how do I do this as I just want one id (RestaurantID)

Comment: Do you have an action method called `RestaurantReservationsPartialView` ? How does it look ?

Comment: Yes its in the top part of my post, the controller

Comment: i don't see it. Make sure you post the relevant part of the code in the question.

Comment: what is the partial view strongly typed to ? Also you probably need to pass a restaurant id to the action method. How is restaurant and restaurantReservationEvents connected ?

Comment: Each restaurant has a list of reservations which store that restaurants id

Comment: Does your main view has the RestuarantId ? how ?

Comment: Yes my index view has a list of restaurants each having a restaurantId. I cannot pass one value to the Partial View as my model is IEnumerable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are **not** calling a partial view from your main view, but invoking an action method using `Html.Action` method which returns a partial view result.

Your `RestaurantReservationsPartialView` action method is passing a list of `Restaurant` objects to it's (partial) view. But from the error message , it looks like your partial view is strongly typed to a list of `RestaurantReservationEvent` objects. You are getting this model type mismatch error because you are passing a wrong type to the partial view.

The solution is to pass the correct type. Since you want to pass the reservation for a specific restaurant, You probably want to accept the restaurant id as a parameter of your action method, use that to get the reservation events and pass that to the view.

Something like this.

```
public ActionResult RestaurantReservationsPartialView(int id)
{
   var events = db.RestaurantReservationEvents.Where(x=>x.RestaurantId==id).ToList();
   return View(events);
}
```

Assuming `RestaurantReservationEvents` is a property on your DbContext of type `DbSet<RestaurantReservationEvent>`. *Please update the linq expression which returns a list of Restaurant to match with your situation*

Now make sure you are passing the restaurant id when calling the action method.

```
<div style="padding-top: 50px;">
   @Html.Action("RestaurantReservationsPartialView",,new { id=3})
</div>
```

Here i hard coded the Id value to `3`.You may replace it with a variable which has the real value.

Comment: Thank you this code works perfect but I am having trouble getting the restaurantsID in the view as I am using @Model.IEnumerable?

Comment: For each restaurant in the collection, you might have a for/foreach loop .Correct ? Use the relevant property (ex : RestaurantId/Id) of your loop variable

Comment: yes Im using a for each loop but the partial view is being called before it goes into that loop